# Which .nt file from the DBpedia dataset contains the triples about DBpedia classes?

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I am working on a DBpedia dataset and using Apache Jena to execute SPARQL over a local Jena TDB dataset. I have downloaded only some of the files from [DBpedia Downloads](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38) so that I could keep the size of my dataset to a minimum, but I get no results when I execute a SPARQL query of the kind:

```
Select distinct * WHERE {
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> ?x ?y
} LIMIT 5
```

However, if I run the same query on the [Virtuoso client](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), I get valid results.

Which .nt file contains the URI triple of the form:

`http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person`
 `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type`
 `http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class`

Meaning, which .nt file in [Downloads](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38), needs to be added in my local Jena TDB dataset?

P.S. I already have Ontology Infobox Types in my dataset which contains triples of the form $object rdf:type $class .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do to figure out *where* triple are coming from is to use a `GRAPH`, as in

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
GRAPH ?g { <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> ?x ?y }
}
LIMIT 20
```

which, using the Virtuoso client, finds the same triples as the query without them, but will show you which graph triples were obtained from, e.g.,

```
http://dbpedia.org                   rdf:type owl:Class
http://dbpedia.org/resource/classes# rdf:type owl:Class
```

Now, I imagine that `http://dbpedia.com` is a default graph that contains the triples from all the others, so the interesting one here is probably `http://dbpedia.org/resource/classes#`.  Based on Ben Companjen's answer, I tried using the Ontology dataset, and when I run the following query (like yours, but without the `LIMIT 5`)

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> ?p ?o
}
```

I get the result that `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> a owl:Class` (it's the next to last row).  If the `LIMIT 5` is present in the original query, you may not be seeing that particular result.

```
$ /usr/local/lib/apache-jena-2.10.0/bin/arq \
    --data ~/Downloads/dbpedia_3.8.owl \
    --query dbpedia.sparql 
-------------------------------------------------------------
| p                   | o                                   |
=============================================================
| rdfs:label          | "person"@en                         |
| rdfs:label          | "persona"@es                        |
| rdfs:label          | "Person"@de                         |
| rdfs:label          | "pessoa"@pt                         |
| rdfs:label          | "personne"@fr                       |
| owl:equivalentClass | <http://schema.org/Person>          |
| rdfs:label          | "Πληροφορίες προσώπου"@el           |
| rdfs:label          | "Oseba"@sl                          |
| owl:equivalentClass | <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person>  |
| rdf:type            | owl:Class                           |
| rdfs:subClassOf     | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent> |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This has been very helpful. I guess this should do the trick.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I hope this has been useful to you.  If an answer answers your question, do be sure to thank the answer-er by accepting (clicking the the checkmark next to it to "Accept").  Happy SPARQLing!

Answer (score 1):

You need the [DBpedia ontology](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/3.8/dbpedia_3.8.owl.bz2). That defines the classes and properties in the `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` namespace.

Comment: Using ontology is also much easier but I needed to find a way of doing the same thing from the n-triples. Thanks though.

Comment: @user2353645 The ontology is in RDF/XML format, which is one serialization of an RDF document.  N-Triples is another serialization format.  Your SPARQL engine, so long as it can read both formats, should work fine with either the RDF/XML format or the N-Triples format.

Comment: Understood. And I suppose this is the only possible approach on a local dataset, i.e. to obtain ontologies from the OWL file and subjects from N-Triples. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Arthur OWL ontologies can be coded in RDF.  Instance data can be encoded as statements in an OWL ontology.  RDF can be serialized in a number of different formats, but they're all still RDF.  You can serialize an ontology in RDF/XML, in N3, in N-Triples, or <your favorite syntax here>. That doesn't have anything to do with whether the data is available locally, coming from somewhere on the internet, or somewhere else entirely.  All that matters is that you've got the RDF in some format, and that your SPARQL engine can read that format.  Once it has been read in, it's all the same.

Comment: It's very likely that the triples you are after are only encoded in the OWL file and not in the N-Triples files. In that case there is no way of doing it using the .nt files :)

Comment: Oh! Did not even think of that! I suppose my dilemma has been resolved . Thank you.

Comment: As Joshua said, if your problem is solved, could you mark the answer that worked best for you by clicking the green checkmark? Thanks.