# Is it possible to retrieve a triple's source dataset in DBPedia?

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

Suppose I queried DBPedia like [this](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20*%20where%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fx%20%3Fy%20%3Fz%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28%3Fx%20%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FAbracadabra%3E%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on):

```
select * where
{
  ?x ?y ?z .
  filter (?x = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Abracadabra>)
}
```

and got a lot of triples as a result:

```
x   y   z  
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Abracadabra     http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs    http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Abrakadabra  
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Abracadabra     http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs    http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Abracadabra  
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Abracadabra     http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs    http://ko.dbpedia.org/resource/아브라카다브라  
...
```

Is it possible to detect which one of [these datasets](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/current/) each triple came from?
I want to download and use locally some of those datasets, but first I have to find out which of them are useful for me, based on their contained triples.

In the worst case I'd like to know what dataset(s) contain(s) rdfs:labels.

P.S. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16401383/2665887) approach doesn't work, ?g is always http://dbpedia.org

Comment: As a side note, it's kind of a code smell to do `{ ?x ?y ?z filter( ?x = <...> ) }`.  Do either `{ <...> ?y ?z }` or `{ values ?x { <...> } ?x ?y ?z }`.

Comment: I know it's bad, but I couldn't quickly figure out how to constraint and print ?x at the same time. Going to read some SPARQL standards a bit later -_-

Comment: The second option I mentioned, `values ?x { <...> } ?x ?y ?z` binds `?x` to the specified value(s).  A good optimizer should recognize that a filter like this has the same effect, but the `values` makes the intent clearer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the directories in the listing that you linked to, I think you'd want to pull down [data from the English Wikipedia](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/current/en/).  That said, there are still lots of files in there.  [The DBpedia Data Set (3.9)](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets) has more information about the different files that you can download.  Perhaps most importantly, it says:

> Find the properties used in the different DBpedia data sets [here](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets39/Properties?v=4xg).

That link brings you to [DBpedia 3.9 Data Set Properties](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets39/Properties), which will answer for you, I think, which properties are in which datasets.  To answer your "worst case" specifically, it says that rdfs:label values are stored in the [Titles](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads39?v=2zd#titles)   dataset. Even though they call it *Titles*, I think it's what you'll find as

```
labels_en.nq.bz2
labels_en.nt.bz2
labels_en.tql.bz2
labels_en.ttl.bz2
```

in the listing that you linked to.  I don't know whether or not there's a way to automate looking up the datasets.  It would be nice if the table in [DBpedia 3.9 Data Set Properties](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets39/Properties) were encoded somewhere and could be queried, because then this would be easy.

Comment: 2ct: I couldn't find a way of querying for those properties either.

Comment: Thanks, I read "DBpedia Data Set (3.9)" carefully before asking, but didn't even notice the link to "DBpedia 3.9 Data Set Properties", they did a good job hiding it :D